# difference between AudioQueue time and AudioQueue Device time

Tags: ios, synchronization, real-time, core-audio

I'm trying to sync music sent from a host iPhone to a client iPhone.. the audio is read using AVAssetReader and sent via packets to the client, which in turns feeds it to a ring buffer, which in turn populates the audioqueue buffers and starts playing.

I was going over the AudioQueue docs and there seems to be two different concepts of a timestamp related to the audioQueue: [Audio Queue Time](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioQueueGetCurrentTime) and [Audio Queue Device Time](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioQueueDeviceGetCurrentTime). I'm not sure how those two are related and when one should be used rather (or in conjunction with) the other.