# Get current time stamp of AudioQueueRef when seeking

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio-streaming, audioqueue

I am working with video/audio stream and using `AudioQueueRef` to play audio. I use current time of `AudioQueueRef` for synchronizing video/ audio frame in real-time. When i seek to the specified time, the current time of `AudioQueueRef` i got is not return the correct value, it just returned continuously value with before of timing. I think the problem is i did not reset all old object of `AudioQueueRef`. But i tried many of method and i did not get the expectation current time value. Anyone has idea for this case? Thank in advanced.

Method i get current time of AudioQueueRef

```
- (double)currentTime {
    double timeInterval = 0;
    AudioTimeStamp timeStamp;

    AudioQueueGetCurrentTime(_AudioQueues, NULL, &timeStamp, NULL);
    timeInterval = 1000 * timeStamp.mSampleTime / self.inFormat.mSampleRate; // convert to miliseconds
    return timeInterval;
}
```

And methods that i tried to reset value when seek. If i use any method below, the current time will return negative value.

```
AudioQueueFreeBuffer(_AudioQueues, _AudioBuffer);
AudioQueueFlush(_AudioQueues);
AudioQueueReset(_AudioQueues);
```

P/S: all things is correct before seeking, after seeking, the timestamp is return continuously value.

Comment: [The link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4130735/1079899) may help you.

Comment: Thank you but my problem is after seeking, i get invalid value of AudioTimeStamp (it seems continuously time stamp, not the timestamp that i did seek).

Comment: Example of timestamp value:
Before seeking: `10, 11, 12`
After seeking to 5: `13, 14, 15...`
And now i temporary stored the time gap between before seeking to after seeking, and `currentTime = currentTime - timeGap`. But it is not the typical method to get current time. I want to get exactly current time using only `AudioQueueGetCurrentTime`.

Comment: I believe the audio queue can't keep the timestamp after seeking, it only keeps the duration it plays. Let's say you are playing an audio file, you seek after playing for 12 seconds and seek to 5 second, after 10 seconds, when you call get current time using `AudioQueueGetCurrentTime`, you will get 22. So you can get real current time by 22-12+5 = 17. The audio buffer may affect the precise, so you'd better stop the audio queue before seek using `AudioQueueStop(queue, true)`.

Comment: Thank you, i will try AudioQueueStop. The trick  `22-12+5 = 17` you said is exactly method I implemented in my program but i don't think it is the typical  so I still want to get current time using only AudioQueueGetCurrentTime.

Comment: I find a function may help if you use `AudioQueueStop(queue, true)` to stop the audio queue before seeking, it is `AudioQueueDeviceGetNearestStartTime`, if it works as I supposed, you can use the current time minus the time `AudioQueueDeviceGetNearestStartTime` returns.

Comment: @KudoCC when i call AudioQueueStop, the current time is reset to 0, 1, 2...

Comment: Well... I think it gives enough precision time using the time offset you seek to plus the current time you get from `AudioQueueGetCurrentTime`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think it can be solved.